# KiCad eeSchema editing - add a corner to a wire

Tags: kicad, schematic

Such a simple thing, but my search of the docs and through discussion groups is coming up with nothing. I've just started shifting from Eagle to KiCad, and it's all going smoothly it seems. But when drawing a schematic, and placing wires, I can't find a way to add a corner to an existing routing wire. I'm using KiCad rev 5.1.12 - on MacOS.

Invariably I'm moving a few components around and a wire ends up as a diagonal, and I just want to put a bend in it to keep everything orthogonal, but can't find a means to do so. Of course, I can easily work around that by deleting the wire and redrawing it with a corner, but oh for an easy single key press to pop a vertex in there and drag it to be a new corner placement.

Thanks if anyone knows how to do that - or if it's just not an option in KiCad for some reason.

Comment: do you mean you need to find the "break wire" function ? it is on the left-mouse button contextal menu (after selecting the wire) If similar to PC version (*I guess it is*)

Comment: Aha - break wire (on the right mouse button) does indeed seem to be what I need!  Thx!  Strangely it doesn't show the break nor attach it to the cursor, so it's invisible and you have to do two moves - break and then 'g' for grab to move the corner at that point.   Thx for that!  Post as an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to close this off, as francoisP notes above, the term KiCad uses is "break" and on the Mac UI at least it shows up in the right-click pop-up menu when hovering over the wire in question.

It could certainly be more clear, and usability could be enhanced. When you've 'broken' the wire, there is no visual indication of any change having occurred. At that point you can press 'g' for grab and move that new vertex around to position the corner where you want it. If you move away though, you can't really tell where the new vertex is, or that there is one at all.

You also don't seem to be able to add a quick key shortcut for the 'break' function unfortunately.

It would be great from a usability point of view if breaking the wire were to attach it to the cursor so that it moved around with mouse movements until you pressed escape, or at very least if breaking it caused it to kink at that point perhaps.

Thanks to francoisP who added the answer (as a comment). I've just tacked this "answer" on here for anyone else looking for this in future.